# how to pass multiples dataType $.ajax POST

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, types

Its my ex:
I need pass datatype multiples variables i dont know if its is ok or wrong, how can do it?

```
var type="text";
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"functions/nameplaylist.php",
    dataType:'json','type',
    data:{
    json:JSON.stringify(items)
    }
});
```

Comment: do you mean returned response could be anything ??

Comment: dataType hint what the ajax response would be like. So you cant have multiple response types.

Comment: remove `,'type'` from `dataType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you cannot pass multiple dataTypes. You use ajax, your process is handle through HTTP. So the header only allow you pass one datatype.
In order to resolve your issue, you should convert your data into JSON type.